# Solutions of $x^p+y^q=y^r+z^p=z^q+x^r$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I'm struggling with the following problem from Terence Tao's "Solving Mathematical Problems":

> Find all positive reals $x,y,z$ and all positive integers $p,q,r$ such that
>   $$x^p+y^q=y^r+z^p=z^q+x^r.$$

Obviously, taking $x=y=z=1$ we can have $p,q,r$ arbitrary. Also, I've found the symmetries of the problem

$$x,y,z,p,q,r \mapsto x,y,z,p,q,r \\
x,y,z,p,q,r \mapsto x,z,y,r,q,p   \\
x,y,z,p,q,r \mapsto y,x,z,q,p,r   \\
x,y,z,p,q,r \mapsto y,z,x,r,p,q   \\
x,y,z,p,q,r \mapsto z,x,y,q,r,p   \\
x,y,z,p,q,r \mapsto z,y,x,p,r,q$$

I was hoping that all solutions follow a simple rule, like $x=y=z$, but unfortunately the solution

$$10,10,\sqrt{190},2,2,1 $$
shows it is not the case. Can I get any help on this please? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've noticed that equality of two exponents (i.e. $p=q$) implies equality of two basis (i.e. $x=y$), and then the solution is

$$z=(2x^p-x^r)^{1/p} $$

where $2x^p-x^r>0$. (Of course, different exponents being equal gives rise to different forms of the solution)

I've also noticed that you could have solutions with $x,y,z,p,q,r$ all distinct:

$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{69}}{4}-\frac{3}{4}\right),y=\frac{1}{2},z=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{69}}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right),p=1,q=2,r=3.$$

This makes me believe that the problem is very general and hence difficult.

Comment: @Macavity you're right. Corrected.

Comment: I don't yet see an elegant approach, but the approach is surely to use implications like $p<q,y<x \implies y^r + z^p < z^q + x^r$ to deduce that two of $(x,y,z)$ and two of $(p,q,r)$ are equal.

Comment: @Slade I think it's a bit more complicated than that. I see that if $y<x$ one can deduce that $y^r<x^r$, but if $p<q$ and in addition $z<1$ then $z^p>z^q$.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, the problem was indeed too complicated, as stated in the errata [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/solving-mathematical-problems/):

> In page 66, problem 44, there is a $=2$ missing at the end of the string of equations, thus $x^p+y^q=y^r+z^p=z^q+x^r=2$.

We still have the solution $x=y=z=1$ for arbitrary $p,q,r$. Say we have a solution $x',y',z'$ where WLOG $x'>1$. That would force $y'<1$ from the first expression, which, in turn forces $z'>1$ from the second expression, which forces $x'<1$ from the third, which is a contradiction.

Thus the only solution is $x=y=z=1$ and $p,q,r \in \mathbb{N}$.

[P.S.

I don't think there is be a closed form for the solution without the $=2$ at the end, but this is based on solely numerical evidence.]